# Recursion issues with my trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public Class AvoidRecursion{
  private static boolean firstRun = true;
    public static boolean isFirstRun(){
      if(firstRun){
        firstRun = false;
        return true;
      }else{
        return firstRun;
      }
   }
}
```

---

```
trigger UpdateSelfManage on Case (after insert, after update) {

  if (AvoidRecursion.isFirstRun())

  {

    //Record Ids
    List<RecordType> rList = new List< RecordType>([SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Case' AND DeveloperName = 'Amend_Enrolment' ]);
    Id caId = !rList.isEmpty() ? rList[0].Id : null;


    //Unique set of Course Enrolments IDs to capture
    Set<ID> setofCEIds = new Set<ID>();


     for (Case c: Trigger.New){
       if ((c.RecordTypeId == caId) && (c.Origin == 'Student Portal') && (c.Subject == 'Self Managed Amendment') && (c.Status == 'Closed')) {
       setofCEIds.add(c.Course_Enrolment__c);
       }
     }


    //If the list has anything in it then loop through the list of Course Enrolments and then through the related cases for each CE. If any of the related cases has the conditions as
    //described below then update the self manage statud to 'Open' and add to the listofCEstoupdate list. When all of the looping through the list of CEs is done then bulk update the list
    //outside of the loop

      if (setofCEIds.size() > 0) {

      //Flag to test if the current CE needs to be updated or not
      Boolean updatethefield = true;

      //List of Course Enrolments to query which also pulls in info from the related case record
      List<Course_Enrolment__c> listofCEs = [SELECT Id, Self_Manage_Status__c, (SELECT Id, RecordTypeId, Origin, Subject, Status, Course_Enrolment__c FROM Cases__r) FROM Course_Enrolment__c WHERE Id in :setofCEIds];

      //New empty list of Course Enrolements to add to and then finally update
      List<Course_Enrolment__c> listofCEstoupdate = new List<Course_Enrolment__c>();


        for (Course_Enrolment__c ce : listofCEs){

          updatethefield = True;

          for (Case rc : ce.Cases__r){

            if ((rc.Status <> 'Closed') && (rc.Origin == 'Student Portal') && (rc.Subject == 'Self Managed Amendment') && (rc.RecordTypeId == caId)){

                updatethefield = False; 
            }
          }

          if (updatethefield == True){

              ce.Self_Manage_Status__c = 'Open';
              listofCEstoupdate.add(ce);
            }
        }

        Update listofCEstoupdate;

      }

    }

}
```

Have been trying to resolve a recursion error and cannot deploy the above trigger to production.

Comment: when you say "cannot deploy" what's blocking the deployment ? any specific errors during deployment ? or any issues in compiling / saving the file in your sandbox ?

Comment: Thanks Vamsi I managed to validate it running only the test class that I created independantly. There are some other issues unrelated that are throwing errors. I added the class at the beginning to deal with a recusion error (ie updating a trigger that updates the trigger and so on....) So it validates now. I just wanted to make sure its ok to deploy to production from this perspective...? Regards

Comment: @DavidLeckenby so are you unable to deploy to production or not? What is your question ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! Yes the code does complile now but I appreciate your help making the code more reliable and efficient. Cheers David

Answer (score 4):

Your `AvoidRecursion` class should be rewritten such that the logic to hold make the changes to the variable are performed in your trigger class. I recommend you use the following pattern:

```
public Class TriggerHelper{
  public static boolean firstRun = true;
}
```

This now becomes a class that is reusable by any of the classes used during the execution to which you can add a `firstRun1`, `firstRun2`, etc as needed or by other trigger helper classes that execute under different contexts.

IMO, the logic to change the value of `firstRun` should be placed in your trigger class rather than exposed as the public method with private variable. That assures it gets executed in your class and not just tested.

```
trigger UpdateSelfManage on Case (after insert, after update) {

  if (TriggerHelper.firstRun){
     TriggerHelper.firstRun = false;
     ....
```

I think you'll find this more reliable. You do not want to place your support class for the boolean within your trigger helper class. The helper class executes and then is finished. When it executes a 2nd time, the value of the boolean will once again be true as it won't have persisted from the first time it was called until the next time it gets called, unless called from another class that persists. That pattern only works from a trigger pattern where you have a dispatcher class and the boolean is located on the dispatcher class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a single class to handle recursion for a trigger, why not use a class to handle any recursion from anywhere in your code?

```
public class TriggerHelper {
    public static Set<String> bypassedMethods;

    public static void registerMethod(String method_name) {
        if (bypassedMethods == null) {
            bypassedMethods = new Set<String>();
        }
        bypassedMethods.add(method_name);
    }

    public static void removeMethod(String method_name) {
        if (bypassedMethods == null) {
            return;
        } else if (bypassedMethods.contains(method_name)) {
            bypassedMethods.remove(method_name);
        }
    }

    public static Boolean isBypassed(String method_name) {
        if (bypassedMethods != null && bypassedMethods.contains(method_name)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is a small class I've come with on a project, and you can avoid recursion by placing a check in your code ("if is bypassed, then do not run") with the `isBypassed` method. And you can register bypassed code with `registerMethod` and remove the bypass with `removeMethod`.

Answer (score -2):

Try the below code:

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger UpdateSelfManage on Case(after insert, after update){
    AvoidRecursion.test(Trigger.new);
}
```

**Apex Class**

```
   public class AvoidRecursion{
   private static boolean firstRun = true;
   public static boolean isFirstRun(){
   if(firstRun){
    firstRun = false;
    return true;
    }
     else{
     return firstRun;
      }
    }
   public static void test(List<Case> Caselist){
   if(AvoidRecursion.isFirstRun()){
    //Record Ids
   List<RecordType> rList = new List< RecordType>([SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType='Case' AND DeveloperName ='Amend_Enrolment']);
   Id caId= !rList.isEmpty()? rList[0].Id:null;
   //Unique set of Course Enrolments IDs to capture
   Set<ID> setofCEIds= new Set<ID>();       
   for (Case c: Caselist){
   if((c.RecordTypeId == caId)&&(c.Origin =='Student Portal')&&(c.Subject== 'Self Managed Amendment')&&(c.Status =='Closed')){
      setofCEIds.add(c.Course_Enrolment__c);
      }
    }
  //If the list has anything in it then loop through the list of Course Enrolments and then through the related cases for each CE.If any of the related cases has the conditions as described below then update the self manage status to 'Open' and add to the listofCEstoupdate list.When all of the looping through the list of CEs is done then bulk update the list outside of the loop
     if(setofCEIds.size()>0){
    //Flag to test if the current CE needs to be updated or not
     Boolean updatethefield =true;
    //List of Course Enrolments to query which also pulls in info from the related case record
     List<Course_Enrolment__c> listofCEs =[SELECT Id, Self_Manage_Status__c, (SELECT Id,RecordTypeId,Origin,Subject, Status,Course_Enrolment__c FROM Cases__r)FROM Course_Enrolment__c WHERE Id in :setofCEIds];
    //New empty list of Course Enrolements to add to and then finally update
     List<Course_Enrolment__c> listofCEstoupdate =new List<Course_Enrolment__c>();
     for(Course_Enrolment__c ce:listofCEs){
     updatethefield =True;
     for(Case rc : ce.Cases__r){
     if((rc.Status == 'Closed')&&(rc.Origin =='Student Portal')&&(rc.Subject =='Self Managed Amendment')&&(rc.RecordTypeId ==caId)){
     updatethefield =False; 
        }
      }
     if(updatethefield == True){
       ce.Self_Manage_Status__c ='Open';
       listofCEstoupdate.add(ce);
          }
        }
       Update listofCEstoupdate;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Will that even compile?? not to mention its not a tigger. Also, what changes did  you make, what problem were you solving, how does this help. Simply posting a code dump does not help anyone much

Answer (score -2):

It is not good approach to use such Boolean to avoid recursion. After some time you have too many boolean in the system, and you don't know when to turn each to off/on.

Better approach is that your trigger will have entering criteria based on logic.
When you collecting the relevant records from trigger.new you should get only the records that have relevant change.
e.g.:

```
for (Case c: Trigger.New){
   if ((c.RecordTypeId == caId) && (c.Origin == 'Student Portal') && (c.Subject == 'Self Managed Amendment') && (c.Status == 'Closed')) {
      //Process the record only if it's new process or it's update and relevant change occur
      if(trigger.isInsert ||
          (trigger.isUpdate && (c.Origin != trigger.oldMap.get(c.id).Origin) || trigger.isUpdate && (c.Subject != trigger.oldMap.get(c.id).Subject) || trigger.isUpdate && (c.Status != trigger.oldMap.get(c.id).Status))){
                    setofCEIds.add(c.Course_Enrolment__c);
            }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: And if a WFR or some other processes causes an update again how will this avoid that?

Comment: if workflow made relevant change then the trigger should run

Comment: I do not think you understand how the order of execution works. If you make a change and the trigger runs and then a wfr makes a change unrelated the trigger will still run because the value of old map and new map still looks like the change was made. They are all they same transaction, hence recursion

Comment: Even if WF update the record, then the trigger will run once more time only. From SF documentation: "If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one more time)"

Comment: Thus recursion. And if you are doing an update on the same object in during updates, boom stack depth. Thus the need to a static property

Comment: Suggest you try it and see it won't cause recursion. ... in trigger write if(field1 was changed) then update field2.  and in workflow on same object write if(field2 was changed) then update field1.  This won't cause recursion, again see SF documentation